# Issues with syntax error: . or operator expected after expression while running program

Tags: prolog, syntax-error

Below is a program in Prolog.

```
domains
 list = integer*
predicates
 nondeterm m(list)
 nondeterm p(list, integer)
clauses
 p([],X):-write(X).
 p([H|T],X):-H>X,p(T,H).
 p([_|T],X):-p(T,X).
 m([]):-write(0).
 m([H|T]):-p(T,H).
goal
 m([5,2,4,3,6,1]).
```

What number will be printed to the screen by the WRITE statement?

```
Unable to launch the program. The following errors appear, I can not fix it.
prog.pl:2:2: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
prog.pl:13:2: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
    2 error(s)
compilation failed
```

Comment: This looks like a Turbo-Prolog program which is not regular Prolog at all. And the error messages are from GNU Prolog. Remove all lines up to and including `clauses`. And remove the last two lines to make it run with GNU Prolog.